# Connection to the port and authorization

Tags: python, authorization, port, rdp

How can I connect to a Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) server port and perform authorization using python 3.5?

For example, I want to connect to port 3389 via RDP using Python.
How to connect to it and log in?

Comment: I think it ultimately depends on what you've tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.It has port connection.

[http://www.curiousefficiency.org/posts/2015/07/asyncio-tcp-echo-server.html[1](http://www.curiousefficiency.org/posts/2015/07/asyncio-tcp-echo-server.html)